# Задание величины ProgressBar на основании выполнения какого-то метода в потоке (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Во ViewModel запускается поток с помощью метода, например `Current.AsyncParser();` 
Так же во ViewModel я создал свойство `ProgressBarValue{}`, которое биндится к `ProgressBar.Value` в XAML.

Как мне реализовать увеличение данного свойства внутри метода `AsyncParser()`, который находится в Model?

Comment: Передавайте в `AsyncParser()` экземпляр `IProgress<T>` (реализуется, к примеру, `Progress<T>`), и вызывайте у него метод `Report(T)`.

Comment: спасибо, залинкую с этой темой http://hashcode.ru/questions/233703#235207

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)