# Работа с контролами из фонового потока

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, многопоточность, c#-faq

Ситуация следующая:

- имеется окно с кнопкой `button1` и меткой `label1`.
- по кнопке запускается какая-то долгая операция, в отдельном потоке.
- по завершению операции нужно вывести результат `label1`.

При попытке поменять значение `label1.Text` код падает с исключением `InvalidOperationException`:

WinForms:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
>
> Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'label1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан.

WPF:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
>
> Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.

Пример кода:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new Thread((s) =>
        {
            var result = Worker.SomeLongOperation();

            // следующая строчка падает c InvalidOperationException:
            this.label1.Text = result;
        })).Start();
}

class Worker
{
    public static string SomeLongOperation()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return "результат";
    }
}
```

Comment: ...в рамках перевода каноничных вопросов и ответов из EnSO

Comment: А где ссылка на оригинальный вопрос? Если это перевод, то не стоит несколько ответов приводить, достаточно один общий собрать из существующих ответов.

Comment: Ответы из http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c/18033198. Оригинальный вопрос не ищется по тексту ошибки, так что я написал как можно более общий случай. Если хотите оформить одним ответом  - редактируйте, ответы общие. Я оформлял по аналогии с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/ и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/.

Comment: Если вопрос достаточно полезен, чтобы его перевести, то перевод должен делать человек, который может выбрать лучшее. Механический перевод, без понимая смысла, существующих ответов на английском -- менее полезен.

Comment: @jfs, вы думаете что я не достаточно компетентен и не могу "выбрать лучшее" между BeginInvoke и async? А вам не приходило в голову, что это два независимых решения, каждое из которых применимо в определенном контексте (который зависит от версии фреймворка и от масштабов проблемы). Тут наоборот, не хватает еще одного подробного ответа про background worker.

Comment: @jfs лучшее, кстати - async/await. и он **ни разу** не упоминался ни в одном из ответов на схожие вопросы на ruSO. Только потому, что это не самое *понятное* и *простое* решение. За Invoke в .NET 4.5 нужно бить по рукам. Но Invoke - это простой костыль. Погуглил, вставил, все работает. Знаете C# лучше меня и можете выбрать - feel free to edit.

Comment: Я не сужу компетентность людей (иногда могу высказаться о качестве *вопроса* / *ответа*). Конкретная тема не важна, важен общий подход к вопросам-переводам. Если вы можете выбрать лучшее, то напишите *один* ответ как я предложил в самом первом комментарии. Кстати, сравнение различных подходов лучше в этот ответ вставить, а не в комментариях к вопросу оставлять.

Comment: Ок, попробую объединить

Comment: Ответ который реально помог в этой ситуации: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/106720/219224](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/106720/219224)

Comment: @РоманАрсеньев он там есть ниже, в части "Решение для .NET 3.5 и более ранних версий". в 4.0+ - лучше использовать нормальное решение.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Решение для .NET 4.0 и более поздних версий

Использовать [Асинхронную модель на основе задач (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh873175.aspx) и ключевые слова [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)-[await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = await Task.Run(() => Worker.SomeLongOperation());

    this.label1.Text = result;
}
```

Преимущества:

- Код значительно короче других вариантов, вызовы записаны в той последовательности, в которой они выполняются.
- Никаких коллбеков и ручной работы с потоками.
- [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx) не дает обработчику события завершиться, но при этом не блокирует UI.

Встроенная поддержка ключевых слова `async`/`await` появились в .NET 4.5 и Visual Studio 2013.

Данное решение также может быть использовано для .NET 4.0 и Silverlight 5, если используется версия Visual Studio не ниже 2012. Для этого нужно установить пакет [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) из NuGet.

## Решение с отображением прогресса выполнения

Если в процессе выполнения нужно отображать прогресс или промежуточные результаты из второго потока, то можно использовать класс [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<string>(s => label1.Text = s);

    string result = await Task.Run(() => Worker.SomeLongOperation(progress));

    this.label1.Text = result;
}

class Worker
{
    public static string SomeLongOperation(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        // Perform a long running work...
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
            progress.Report(i.ToString());
        }
        return "результат";
    }
}
```

`Progress` захватывает [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) в момент создания, и использует его для выполнения операций, избавляя от ручных вызовов Invoke.

## Решение для .NET 3.5 и более ранних версий

Использовать `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`:

```
// WinForms:
this.label1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.label1.Text = result));

// WPF:
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.label1.Content = result));
```

Для .NET 2.0, в котором еще не было лямбд, эквивалентный код записывается с помощью анонимных делегатов:

```
// WinForms:
this.label1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate { this.label1.Text = result; });

// WPF:
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(delegate { this.label1.Content = result; });
```

Полный код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new Thread((s) =>
        {
            var result = Worker.SomeLongOperation();

            this.label1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.label1.Text = result));

        })).Start();
}
```

`BeginInvoke` поставит код на выполнение в тот поток, в котором был создан `label1` и продолжит выполнение фонового потока. При использовании `Invoke` вместо `BeginInvoke` фоновый поток будет приостановлен до завершения выполнения кода в UI потоке.

Comment: О, это правильный ответ. А зачем вы сделали его общим?

Comment: @VladD это перевод http://stackoverflow.com/a/18033198/1985167. Видимо, автор решил не зарабатывать на этом репутацию :).

Comment: @andreycha: Намёк понял.

Comment: Потому что это перевод http://stackoverflow.com/a/18033198/1988244 с адаптацией. Причем [вопрос оттуда переведен](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11861/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gui-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0), но он негуглибелен по тексту ошибки, и правильных подробных ответов в нем нет. Я попробовал сформулирвоать в более общем виде.

Comment: @andreycha репутация, кстати, все равно капает за плюсы на вопрос :)

Comment: Дополнил ответ указанием, как можно использовать шаблон TAP на .NET 4.0. Может тогда и заголовок исправить?

Comment: подправил, не уверен насколько удачно

Comment: _"{ this.label1.Text = result; }"_ -- из-за этого будет неприятный сюрприз с замыканием. см.  [Почему делегат добавляет неправильные данные?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645)

Comment: @Stack не "будет", а "возможен"

Comment: Можно добавить еще и SynchronizationContext который можно использовать и без UI

if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

            Sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

используя Send или Post

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18033198/276994

Comment: Зачем `Task.Delay(500).Wait()`, почему не просто `Thread.Sleep(500)`? И лямбы -- это фича компилятора C# 3.0, который доступен начиная с VS2008, а не фича .NET Framework.

Comment: @Raider это общий ответ. считаете что в нем что-то не так, и хотите это исправить - исправляйте.

Comment: @Raider `Task.Delay(500).Wait()` пришел из вопроса-оригинала на enSO вместе с остальным кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть пример для UI для безопасного вызова из не главного потока.

Чтобы взаимодействовать с элементами интерфейса из другого thread

```
  void SomeAsyncMethod()
  {
      // Do some work             

      if (this.InvokeRequired)
      {
          this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
              {
                  DoUpdateUI();

              }
          ));
      }
      else
      {
          DoUpdateUI();
      }
  }

  void DoUpdateUI()
  {
      // Your UI update code here
  }
```

Здесь **this.Invoke** метод контрола

Comment: Про Invoke сказано в ответе выше :) сам Invoke внутри делает проверку на this.InvokeRequired, так что она избыточна в вызывающем коде.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен, но как вариант пойдет:)
Давно еще по забытым причинам приходилось использовать именно такую конструкцию.