# Работа с Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть 2 программы. Одна WinPhone приложение, другая WPF. В обоих используется `Dispatcher` для доступа к элементам UI из потока. Вот код из WinPhone

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => RateTextBox.Text = rate)
```

Здесь все работает. `Dispatcher` идет как объект, есть метод `BeginInvoke`.

Вот код WPF

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBox1.Text = content)
```

Здесь `Dispatcher` идет как класс, а не объект. Я не могу понять почему. Пытался испробовать разные конструкции, но в итоге идет ошибка

> Ошибка 2   Невозможно преобразовать "лямбда-выражение" к типу "System.Delegate", поскольку он не является делегатом

Не могу понять почему ошибка и почему в двух проектах "разные" Dispatcher'ы, В WinPhone приложении подрублены свои мобильные библиотеки с коробки, ничего не добавлял от себя.
В WPF Добавил WindowsBase.dll откуда взял ссылку на `System.Windows.Threading` где и лежит `Dispatcher`.

Кто может разъяснить ситуацию? А то я уже больше недели бьюсь над этими вопросами. Почему на WinPhone все прекрасно работает как надо, а на WPF нет.

Добавлено после:

Теперь все компилица, но не выводит результат запроса. Я испробовал код на консольном приложении, где не требуется Dispatcher. Такой код

```
(content => Console.WriteLine(content))
```

Здесь все работает. Но я добавил Dispatcher.

```
(content => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Console.WriteLine(content))))
```

И консоль пуста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я бы с радостью, но все что мне предложили в ответах не дает результата, хоть и компилируется.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вам нужно явно указать тип делегата - любой, но конкретный тип. `BeginInvoke` принимает `Delegate` -  делегат любого типа.

Для компиляции лямбды как делегата компилятор должен знать тип. Он его не может вывести ни из сигнатуры метода - потому что там любой типа разрешен - ни из лямбды - потому что нет однозначного механизма вывода конкретного типа делегата только по параметрам и возвращаемому значению. Вот он и падает с ошибкой.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text = content));
```

P.S. Не используйте `Invoke` - намучаетесь. Используйте [async/await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/177221).

Answer (score 6):

WPF писался в до-дженериковую эру, и в нём осталось много наследия: нетипизирвоанные коллекции, невнятно типизированные делегаты и т. п. WinRT создавался уже в современную эпоху, поэтому в нём есть адекватные перегрузки методов. Лечится это просто — добавлением extension-методов. Например:

```
public static class Exts
{
    public static void BeginInvoke (this Dispatcher @this, Action action)
    {
        @this.BeginInvoke(action);
    }

    public static void BeginInvoke (this Dispatcher @this, DispatcherPriority priority, Action action)
    {
        @this.BeginInvoke(action, priority);
    }
}
```

При наличии такого класса будут работать привычные вам перегрузки.

Впрочем, по возможности стоит использовать адаптированный для async/await метод — `InvokeAsync`:

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => RateTextBox.Text = rate);
```

Comment: WPF вышел как часть 3.0, спустя почти год после выхода генериков в 2.0. В нем должны были быть генерики :)

Comment: @PashaPash Должны быть, но нет. WPF начали писать до появления дженериков, а когда появились дженерики, было уже поздно всё переделывать.

Comment: @PashaPash Из сорцов `Grid`: *09/24/2003 : olego - Created (in griddy prototype branch)*. :)

Answer (score 4):

Компилятор не может вывести из вашей лямбды конкретный делегат, а потому сигнализирует об ошибке. Скастуйте его например так:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => RateTextBox.Text = rate));
```

Answer (score 1):

К вопросу о консоли. `Dispatcher` - это не какая-то магия, а класс, дающий доступ к стандартному виндовому циклу обработки сообщений. В консольном прилдожении никто не крутит этот цикл в основном потоке - вот и не работает `Dispatcher`.