# Изменение данных в разных потоках

Tags: c#, диаграммы, многопоточность

Проект WindowsForms. Имеется класс Grapher. Данный класс содержит в себе классы ChartManager и DataManager. В классе ChartManager создается объект Chart и передается на форму при помощи вот такой конструкции:

```
//ChartManager.cs
public delegate void OnChartReadyHandler(object sender, Chart chart);
public event OnChartReadyHandler OnChartReady;

//Инициализация чарта
public void ChartInitialize()
{
    // Сообщаем всем, что чарт готов
    OnChartReady(this, main_chart);
}
```

Таким образом Chart попадает в Grapher и далее в форму. Инициализация проходит нормально.

В DataManager я создаю поток, который читает данные из файла и отправляет их в чарт все тем же способом:

```
//DataManager.cs
public delegate void OnDataUpdateHandler(DataItem data_item);
public event OnDataUpdateHandler OnDataUpdate;

private void DataReader()
{
    .....
    OnDataUpdate(data_item);
    ....
}
```

В Grapher, перед тем, как отправлять данные, я подготавливаю массивы и сам чарт:

```
data_for_chart.clear();    
foreach (Series series in chart_manager.main_chart.Series)
{
    series.Points.Clear();
}
```

за что получаю вот такую ошибку:

Дополнительные сведения: Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'MainChart' не из того потока, в котором он был создан.

Понятно, что Chart создавался в основном потоке, а я пытаюсь его поменять в потоке, который читает данные, но ведь и data_for_chart тоже создавался в основном потоке. Тем не менее он очищается, а чарт нет. Как выйти из такой ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ограничение на работу их другого потока действует только на контролы (Chart - это контрол). Отрисовка контрола происходит в основном потоке. Изменение данных, на основе которых происходит отрисовка, может сильно и непредсказуемо перекосить контрол. Поэтому в .NET есть проверка, которая предотвращает смену данных контрола из фонового потока.

Массивы же можно менять откуда угодно - они не рисуются напрямую, просто лежат в памяти. Поэтому в вас не падает при осчистке массива, но падает при очистке Series.

Возможные решения расписаны в ответе к вопросу [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/177221).