# button_click не находится в том же потоке, что и переменные

Tags: c#, winforms

Я запускаю форму Chat из формы Form1, в первой запускается сервер с клиентом, но когда я пытаюсь ввести сообщение, событие Send_button отправляет сообщение в поток, в котором ни клиент ни сервер, ни клиент не запущены.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace easy_chat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Form1 form = new Form1();
            //form.Show();
        }


        private void HostButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chat form = new Chat();
            form.StartServer();
        }

        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            Chat form = new Chat();
            IPAddress ip;
            bool isipaddr = IPAddress.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out ip);
            if (isipaddr)
            {
                form.StartClient(ip);
                form1.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Ip");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Chat.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace easy_chat
{
    public partial class Chat : Form
    {
        private Server serv;
        private Client cli;
        public IPAddress ip;
        public Chat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serv = new Server();
            cli = new Client();
        }

        private void TextUpdater()
        {
            while (cli.IsClientRunning)
            {
                String MessagesString = "";
                Message_Box.Text = "";
                foreach (string msg in cli.Messages)
                {
                    MessagesString += msg + "\n";
                }
                Message_Box.Text = MessagesString;
            }
        }
        public void Send_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cli.SendBuffer.Add(Message_Box.Text);
        }
        public void StartServer()
        {
            Chat form = new Chat(); 
            serv.StartServer();
            cli.RealIp = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            cli.StartClient();
            form.Text = "Server";
            form.Show();
            Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater));
        }
        public void StartClient(System.Net.IPAddress ip)
        {
            Chat form = new Chat();
            cli.RealIp = ip;
            cli.StartClient();
            form.Text = "Client connected to: " + ip + ":" + cli.port;
            form.Show();
            Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater));
        }
    }
}
```

В отладке видно, что клиент в обработчике `Send_button_Click` не запущен, хотя он был запущен незадолго до этого в `StartClient`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно вы подразумеваете под "событие Send_button отправляет сообщение в поток, в котором ни клиент ни сервер, ни клиент не запущены". Что-то не работает? Выбрасывается исключение? или просто ничего не происходит? Поля классов - общие для всех потоков. Клиент и сервер - тоже.  Из вашего кода видна только проблема работы с контролами из фонового потока, при которой вы бы получали [стандартное исключение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418461/177221). Если вы его получаете - воспользуйтесь решением по ссылке. Если происходит что-то еще - напишите, что именно.

Comment: ничего не происходит. просто, когда я в отладки смотрю
'cli.SendBuffer.Add(Message_Box.Text)'

Comment: значит отлаживайте ту часть кода, которая берет сообщения из SendBuffer и отправляет. Или ту часть кода, которая получает сообщения. В любом случае, проблема не в том коде, который вы привели в вопросе. (в нем тоже есть проблема, но она у вас не выстреливает из-за в целом нерабочего приложения). Приведите код клиента и сервера в вопросе. Сейчас у вас приведено все, кроме самого проблемного кода.

Comment: @PashaPash ничего не происходит. просто, когда я в отладки смотрю

'cli.SendBuffer.Add(Message_Box.Text)'

ставлю на этом точку останова, и навожу на cli, то сама переменная пуста, в нее добавляются только сообщения. а должен работать сам клиент. Если ставить точку осанова в другом месте, в 'StartServer()' например, там будет видно что сервер и клиент работают, что видно будет на этих переменных

Comment: какая именно переменная пуста? cli? пуста - это null? или еще как-то?

Comment: @PashaPash [pic](http://rghost.ru/67JcNPyFQ/image.png)
sendbutton_click выполняется же после того как стартует клиент, поэтому мне и непонятно, если я добавляю в коллекцию слова, то они остаются там

Comment: скорее всего он останавливается где-то между  StartClient и sendbutton_click. можете проверить что это один и тот же объект (make object id по правой кнопке).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30424/discussion-between-max619-and-pashapash).

Comment: а, все, дошло. у вас по клику на StartClient создается новая форма. со своим cli (2) внутри. но запускаете вы при этом клиент cli (1) в *оригинальной* форме, на которой был вызван StartClient. По клику в новой форме вы добавляете сообщение в незапущенный клиент form.cli.

Comment: @PashaPash и как же сделать так, чтобы они были в одной форме. Кстати, запускается только одна форма.

Comment: запускается одна - но создается несколько. клиент вы запускаете в одной, а показываете - другую. Уберите `Chat form = new Chat();` из `StartClient` и `StartServer`. замените `form.Text = "..."; form.Show();` на `Text = ".."; Show();`. и заодно упоминания `form1` из `ConnectButton_Click` уберите.

Comment: и добавьте Invoke, как вам уже насоветовали ниже - когда клиент заработает - начнет падать. когда переоткроют - оформлю как ответ с полным кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из комментариев:

Проблема в том, что по нажатию `ConnectButton_Click` вы создаете два объекта формы `Chat`:

Первый создается в `ConnectButton_Click`:

```
private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    Chat form = new Chat(); <--
```

он получает свой собственный экземпляр `Client cli` внутри (#1).

после этого вы вызываете `StartClient`, в котором создаете еще одну форму `Chat`, с собственным экземпляр `Client cli` внутри (#2). Которую вы показываете, и в которой кликаете кнопку:

```
public void StartClient(System.Net.IPAddress ip)
{
    Chat form = new Chat(); // создали #2
    cli.RealIp = ip; 
    cli.StartClient(); // запустили клиент #1
    form.Text = "Client connected to: " + ip + ":" + cli.port;
    form.Show(); // показали форму #2 с незапущенным клиентов внутри
    Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater)); // запустили пулинг сообщений из рабочего клиента #1
}
```

обработчик клика вызывается в той форме, которую вы отобразили - #2

```
public void Send_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cli.SendBuffer.Add(Message_Box.Text); // добавляет текст для отправки в буфер неподключенного клиента
}
```

Что стоит сделать:

Убрать лишние создаваемые формы:

```
public void StartClient(System.Net.IPAddress ip)
{
    // Chat form = new Chat(); <-- не нужна
    cli.RealIp = ip;
    cli.StartClient();
    this.Text = "Client connected to: " + ip + ":" + cli.port; // <-- у текущей формы, в которой запущен клиент
    this.Show(); // <-- у текущей формы, в которой запущен клиент
    Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater));
}
```

...

```
private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Form1 form1 = new Form1(); <-- не нужна
    Chat form = new Chat();  <-- форма клиента - #1
    IPAddress ip;
    bool isipaddr = IPAddress.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out ip);
    if (isipaddr)
    {
        form.StartClient(ip);
        // form1.Close();  <-- не нужна
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Ip");
    }
}
```

И вот после этого сообщения у вас пойдут, и выстрелит новая проблема - т.к. форма, в которой запущен TextUpdater, начнет показываться на экране. После первого отображения формы на экране winforms включит проверку, которая запрещает обращаться к контролам из фоновых потоков, и ваш TextUpdater начнет падать. Самое простое решение, в вашем случае - использовать таймер вместо отдельного потока, как предложил @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev - бросить таймер на форму, настроить его, добавить обработчик:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String MessagesString = "";
    Message_Box.Text = "";
    foreach (string msg in cli.Messages)
    {
        MessagesString += msg + "\n";
    }
    Message_Box.Text = MessagesString;
}
```

и заменить

```
Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater));
```

на

```
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Строкой

```
Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater));
```

Вы запускаете функцию `TextUpdater` в другом потоке (назовем его `T2`), отличном от потока, в котором "выполняется" `UI` (`T1`). В строке `Message_Box.Text = "";` (где `Message_Box` скорее всего какой-нибудь `TextBox` или `Label`) Вы пытаетесь изменить контрол, который был создан в потоке `UI` (т.е. `T1`) из потока `T2` - этого делать нельзя. Чтобы выполнить изменение контрола в "своем" потоке, нужно воспользоваться [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь

```
Thread Texter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TextUpdater));
```

вы запускаете `TextUpdater` в другом потоке.

Пользователь **Donil** уже описал причину этой проблемы и решение с помощью метода `Invoke`.

В случае с WinForms есть еще один способ избежать этой проблемы - использовать контрол `Timer` вместо потоков. Вы можете создать его через дизайнер или из кода.

Создайте таймер, установите ему необходимый `Interval` в миллисекундах (например, 100 = 0.1 секунда). Создайте событие `Tick` и опишите его следующим образом, а затем включите таймер (`Enabled` = `true`).

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String MessagesString = "";
    Message_Box.Text = "";
    foreach (string msg in cli.Messages)
    {
        MessagesString += msg + "\n";
    }
    Message_Box.Text = MessagesString;
}
```

Каждую 0.1 секунду будет выполняться метод `Timer_Tick`. Данное событие выполняется **в UI потоке**, что решает вашу проблему, а также позволяет контролировать частоту выполнения во избежание излишних вычислений. Принято считать, что это самый корректный подход для WinForms-приложений.

Comment: Спасибо за правильное решение, но это не то в чем заключалась проблема

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev, можете дописать свой вариант для работы контролами в общий ответ -  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/177221 - с контекстом - в каких случаях стоит его использовать (пулинг/отображение буфера, заполняемого фоновым потоком)?

Comment: @PashaPash Добрый день. Ответ по этой ссылке очень подробный и качественный. Сомневаюсь, что мне хватит понимания принципов работы `Timer`, чтобы описать его в подобном виде. Был бы рад почитать, если бы вы *(возможно, взяв этот ответ за основу)* добавили этот подход с подробным описанием.