# Как передать переменную из функции в функцию c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно передать переменную vyvod в функцию temp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using xNet;

namespace pogoda
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequest();
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.CharacterSet = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25";
            string vyvod = request.Get("http://pogoda.tut.by/city/minsk").ToString();
            // Data is geting. start multithear         
            Thread th = new Thread(temp);
            th.Start();

        }
        public void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void temp(){
            string temp = vyvod.Substring("<span class=\"temp-i\">", "</span>");
            temp = temp.Replace("&deg;", "°");
            label2.Text = temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: у вас переменная `vyvod` не объявлена. должно быть `string vyvod = ...`. и строка с Substring не компилируется.

Comment: исправил немного. Вы xNet подключили?

Comment: а, там метод расширения. ну ок, ответ все равно от этого не зависит :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Через замыкание:

```
Thread th = new Thread(() => temp(vyvod));
th.Start();

public void temp(string vyvod)
{
}
```

вот только со сменой значения label2.Text из фонового потока у вас будут проблемы - посмотрите вопрос [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/).

Comment: с замыканиями могут быть сюрпризы. я добавил пример в мой ответ.

Comment: @Stack это скорее не сюрприз, а один из примеров, почему нельзя использовать одну переменную для двух разных целей :)

Comment: Я бы сказал, иллюстрация того, что значение _переменной_ может _меняться_.

Comment: @VladD это просто особенность замыканий. но совсем не повод отказываться от них, как в примере http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480646/177221

Comment: @PashaPash: Как это отказываться? Я без них жить не могу!

Answer (score 2):

Вместо Thread лучше использовать Task и async\await.
А в Thread можно передать ссылку на объект - так:

```
var t = new Thread(handler);
t.Start(data);
...

void handler(object o) {
   var data = (DataType)o;
   // ...
}
```

---

Можно использовать замыкание, но из-за этого могут быть сюрпризы (пример ниже в конце ответа).

```
var vyvod = ...
var t = new Thread(() => temp(vyvod));
t.Start();
...

public void temp(string vyvod)
{
}
```

---

Пример сюрприза с замыканиями.
Если переменная, которая находится в замыкании, после запуска потока и до ее использования в потоке, будет изменена, то получим не то, что ожидали.

```
var m = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var s = "123"; 
var t = new Thread(() => {
    m.WaitOne();  // - поток может запуститься не сразу 
    temp(s);  // s в замыкании. и казалось бы, что temp получит "123"
});
t.Start();    // запускаем поток
s = "321";    // меняем значение
m.Set();

static void temp(string s) { 
   Console.WriteLine(s);       //  выводит "321"
}
```

---

Еще один пример с замыканием [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645).