# Изменения GUI из разных потоков С#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, gui

```
class test
{
   public List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    public int nThreads = 0;
    public int maxThreads = 5;

    public void DoWork(object data)
    {
        string message = (string)data;
        //MessageBox.Show(message);        


    }

    public void CreateThread(object data)
    {
        if (nThreads >= maxThreads)
            return;
        Thread newThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        threads.Add(newThread);
        newThread.IsBackground = true;
        newThread.Start(data);
        nThreads++;


    }

    public void WindUpThreads()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("count: " + nThreads.ToString());
        for(int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
        {
            if (threads[i].IsAlive == false)
            {
                threads[i].Abort();
                threads.RemoveAt(i);
               //MessageBox.Show("removing at " + i.ToString());
            }

        }

        nThreads = threads.Count;
    }

}
```

Мне нужно в методе `DoWork` изменять данные в `listbox`, но я не хочу привязывать логику к элементам управления. Как лучше поступить в таком случае?

В общем я решил пойти самым простым путем и передал делегат в тред:

```
   public delegate void TestDeleg(string message);
public class Data
{
    public TestDeleg deleg;
    public string mess;
    }

public void DoWork(object data)
{
    Data d = (Data)data;
    d.deleg(d.mess);
    //string message = (string)data;
    //MessageBox.Show(d.mess);      
    return;


}
```

В цикле теперь передаю класс с запакованным данными:

```
Data d = new Data();
d.deleg = AddItem;
d.mess = strings[counter];
thTest.CreateThread((object)d);
```

Ну и сам метод, который добавляет строку в листбокс:

```
public void AddItem(string message)
{

    //listBox1.Items.Add(message);
    if(InvokeRequired)
        listBox1.Invoke( (Action)( () => { listBox1.Items.Add(message); } ) );
    else
        listBox1.Items.Add(message);

}
```

Теперь почему-то цикл никогда не заканчивается и треды не завершаются, метод, который должен очищать треды почему-то не срабатывает.

UPD: Кажется, причина, по которой интерфейс не обновлялся, выяснилась. Основная часть моей программы была такой:

```
while (flag == true)
{
    if (counter >= dataCount)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    while (thTest.nThreads < thTest.maxThreads)
    {
        if (flag == false)
            break;

        thTest.CreateThread(strings[counter]);

        counter++;
    }

    thTest.WindUpThreads();

    if (flag == false)
    {
        do
        {
            thTest.WindUpThreads();

        } while (thTest.nThreads != 0);
    }

}
```

И запускался этот код по нажатию на кнопку. Получается, что цикл крутился в основном потоке и поэтому ui не принимал сообщения об изменении. Когда я вынес уже этот код в отдельный поток (получается один поток создает другие и управляет ими), то все стало на свои места.

Comment: Если вы не хотите привязывать логику к элементам управления, пользуйтесь MVVM и обновляйте в фоне вью-модель.

Comment: _`listBox1.Invoke( (Action)( () => { listBox1.Items.Add(message); } ) );`_ --  так у вас не те данные могут оказаться в listbox. чтобы такого не было, в listBox1.Invoke надо передать делегат на AddItem и message. посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Comment: Я что-то не совсем догнал. У меня получается что AddItem описан в классе формы, я его передаю в DoWork и там вызываю. Почему там могут оказаться не те данные? И как я передам в listBox1.Invoke делегат на Additem, если я invoke в этом Additem вызываю - получится рекурсия какая-то.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин _"Почему там могут оказаться не те данные?"_ -- почитайте про 'сюрприз' с замыканиями [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478220/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-c/478252#478252)

Comment: @АлександрПушкин _"если я invoke в этом Additem вызываю - получится рекурсия какая-то"_ -- нет. посмотрите мой ответ. я его дополнил про "рекурсию".

Comment: @Stack, спасибо! В самом деле сейчас работает, но как-то странно. У меня в конце обработчика нажатия кнопки идет строка listBox1.Items.Add("Done"). Так почему-то "Done" идет первым в списке, а данные, которые должны потоками добавляться - потом. Почему так происходит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: @АлександрПушкин _"почему-то "Done" идет первым в списке, а данные, которые должны потоками добавляться - потом."_ -- судя по всему один поток добавляет данные раньше других, пока они запускаются и т.д. Вместо Thread лучше использовать Task. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476910/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-c/476958#476958) см update.

Comment: @Stack, окей, спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин _"данные, которые должны потоками добавляться - потом."_ -- проблемы бывают из-за замыкания. см. [Почему делегат добавляет неправильные данные?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Нужно вашу логику отделить от представления. Представить ваше "сердце" приложения как некоторую штуку, которая принимает "команды" из UI и отправляет информацию об изменении состояния - "события". В главном потоке слушать события UI и отправлять в "сердце" соответствующие им команды; подписаться на события основной логики и в соответствий с происходящим перерисовывать ваш UI.

Посмотрите на [IObservable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) и [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

И общие замечания - не рекомендуется создавать потоки руками. Поток - это достаточно тяжелая сущность. Многопоточность реализуется через различные библиотеки, где примитивы несколько интереснее и более удобные, чем потоки. Куда смотреть - [Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx), [Task Parrallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx); читать - Jeffrey Richter, CLR via C# последнюю редакцию, главу про многопоточность.

Comment: Тогда получается, что мне нужно подписываться на событие в каждом созданном треде? А если тредов будет много, не слишком ли это нагрузит систему? И нужно ли от них отписываться, если я собираюсь удалить тред?

Comment: Подписаться только в основном потоке, в котором обновляется UI. В нём же слушать события контролов и формировать из них команды. О потокобезопасности "сердца" - это отдельный разговор. Опять же - непонятно откуда у вас будет "много тредов", и что такое - "слишком много". Рекомендую прочитать главу Рихтера про многопоточное программирование (там же про async/await).

Comment: Получается мне нужно полностью логику менять? Потому что в основном потоке я не могу подписаться на событие в конкретном треде в текущей версии кода.

Comment: Я понял, хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, вы можете в потоках класть данные для `ListBox` в какую-нибудь коллекцию из [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), а в основном (GUI) треде брать оттуда элементы и пихать их в целевой `ListBox`.

Лично я предпочел бы использовать [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) следующим образом:

1. В потоках добавляем элементы.
2. В GUI-треде по таймеру забираем и очищаем.

Comment: Да, в принципе можно, но по-моему это очень серьезный подход. Вроде как можно это через события реализовать, только во-первых не совсем понятно как это сделать, а во-вторых, не будет ли это слишком ресурсозатратно.

Answer (score 0):

- Завести класс, хранящий состояние `DoWork` для отображения.
- Передать в `DoWork` делегат или объект `presenter`, который будет отображать состояние на `listbox` (используя `BeginInvoke`)
- Вызывать периодически `presenter` из под `DoWork`

Comment: А можно ли в DoWork передать делегат, который объявлен в форме, задача которого изменять данные на форме?

Comment: @АлександрПушкин Можно, если обернуть его вызов в `BeginInvoke` или `Invoke`

Comment: не подскажете как это сделать? Тред ведь только объект принимает, а преобразовать делегат в объект это наркомания какая-то.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин Передать в `DoWork` свой объект или `Tuple`, где одно из полей будет делегат.

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно в методе DoWork изменять данные в listbox

Если метод DoWork вызывается из разных потоков, то это можно проверить и данные передать в UI-поток, примерно так:

```
public void DoWork(object data) {
  if (listbox.InvokeRequired)
    listbox.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(DoWork), data);
  else
    listbox.Items.Add((string)data);
}
```

На первый взгляд выглядит как рекурсия, но **это не рекурсия**, т.к. метод BeginInvoke ставит вызов делегата в очередь, элементы которой обрабатывается в UI-потоке.
Другой пример передачи в UI-поток данных из разных потоков [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645).

---

Если надо отделить модель/данные от UI, то пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474635/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B/474645#474645) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-mvp-winforms/474676#474676).

Comment: Да, но это уже привязывание логики к интерфейсу, хотелось бы этого избежать.

Comment: _"привязывание логики к интерфейсу, хотелось бы этого избежать"_ -- добавил в ответ ссылку на пример.