# Как правильно работать с элементами формы и с самой формой из других потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Например есть клиент, который общается с сервером, приходят данные, которые нужно частично выводить на формы. Пробовал через `Dispatcher`, что-то всё равно ругается на `STA`. Может нужно какой бэграундворкер для апдейта формы?

Есть кэлбэк метод который вызывается когда сокет заканчивает приём данных, он вызывает функцию, в ней в зависимости от ответа меняется контрол, Dispatcher пробовал, не помогает, требует STA. Добавлял [STAThread] для кэлбэка сокета, ничего не помогает, есть идеи? Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: вызываю из ReceiveSocketCallback

    Вызвано исключение: "System.InvalidOperationException" в    PresentationCore.dll
    System.InvalidOperationException: Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA, поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов UI.

      AuthWindow.Instance.UpdateErrorBoxMessage(AuthMessages.ErrorMessages[2]);<code>
    public void UpdateErrorBoxMessage(string message)
        {
            _tbErrors.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                _tbErrors.Text = message;
            }));
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
private void AsyncHandler(object data)
{
    tickCount++;
    Action action = () => textBox1.Text = tickCount.ToString();
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

или посмотрите примеры асинхронного программирования c# с операторами async и await