# INotifyPropertyChanged из Task'a

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding, windows-10-mobile

C# UWP Windows 10.
В классе, который реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, есть некая строка к которой привязан `TextBlock`, работает все отлично, но в одном из случаев строке присваивается значения из другого потока `Task` и UI не реагирует на изменения.

Собственно вопрос - как заставить UI обновиться?

Пробовал присваивать значение через `Dispatcher` окна - не работает.

**UPD**

Вызов обновления переменной происходит в другом потоке:

```
...    
await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Balance = Account.GetBalance();
    });
...
```

Код сеттера

```
public string Balance
{
    get{...}
    set
    {
        _balance = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Все компилируется, нету никаких ошибок, просто когда код выполняется в `Task`е - обновление UI не происходит, по дебаггеру значение меняется.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: @Serginio как это относится к `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `DataBinding`? Тем более у меня нету доступа к форме из модели, взаимодействие в эту сторону возможно только через ивенты

Comment: @SYL: Думаю, самым прямым.

Comment: @SYL: «Пробовал присваивать значение через `Dispatcher` окна - не работает». Что это за описание, вы ж программист, надеюсь? Давайте код, и вместо «не работает» точное описание ошибки (exception? не компилируется?). И да, если `Task` у вас бежит в другом потоке, то: (1) вы должны себе поставить вопрос, почему в другом, правильно ли это? (2) если всё же правильно, `Dispatcher` — верный путь, скорее всего ошибка в вашем коде.

Comment: Это относится к тому, что ты должен вызвать изменение в потоке UI

Comment: @VladD Обновил вопрос

Comment: @SYL: О, это уже намного лучше. Что-то я сомневаюсь в `Window.Current`, правильно ли оно сработает. Попробуйте разбить на куски: `var w = Window.Current; var d = w.Dispatcher; ...`, и посмотрите, то ли окно вам приходит.

Comment: @VladD по идее то, возвращается `Windows.UI.Core.Dispatcher`.

Comment: @SYL: Вопрос в том, **тот ли** это диспетчер. Может быть, вы оказываетесь не в том потоке, и у него свой диспетчер. И ещё, гляньте всё же, не бросается ли где-нибудь исключение. Не может что-то просто так молча не работать, это ж не PHP.

Comment: @SYL: Поставьте breakpoint в сеттере свойства, и проверьте, (1) вызывается ли он вообще, (2) если да, то в главном ли потоке.

Comment: @VladD Вызывается. Так же пробовал использовать `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` и через ссылку на окно в котором находится текстовое поле `App.shell.Dispatcher` - все тот же результат

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39337/discussion-between-syl-and-vladd).

Comment: Я для этих целей использую SynchronizationContext  http://infostart.ru/public/417830/ правда там проще использовать put

Comment: @Vlad В общем полная лажа