# C# net EventHandler: создания события из другого потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть Класс с циклом в отдельном потоке. Есть EventHandler и подписка на него в другом классе. Как из цикла в другом потоке безопасно создать событие? При попытке создать его и к примеру создать запись в текстбоксе само собой вылетает исключение с сообщением попытки доступа из другого потока.

Выдержки из кода:

1. `public event EventHandler<NewDataEventArgs> NewData;` - объявление события
2. `NewData(this, e);` - вызов события в потоке

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Так как обработчик события вызывается в том потоке, в котором было вызвано событие, у Вас получается ситуация, что Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к `элементу управления` из другого потока (отличного от UI) - а делать этого нельзя.

Для того что бы это "обойти" есть несколько вариантов, приведу некоторые из них:

**1 Вариант**

Можно воспользоваться [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

1) Получаем `SynchronizationContext`, важно получить его именно для UI поэтому где-нибудь в CodeBehind формы пишем:

```
_context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

2) Далее в Вашем обработчике события, который срабатывает при `NewData(this, e);` необходимо использовать полученный контекст синхронизации, для того что бы безопасно доступиться к UI элементу

```
_context?.Post(s =>
{
   // Здесь пишите код, который получает доступ к контролу
}, null);
```

**2 Вариант**

В обработчике события, который срабатывает при `NewData(this, e);` можно обратиться к вашему элементу управления и вызвать метод [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) в случае `WinForms`

```
myControl.Invoke(myDelegate);
```

либо использовать [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx)  в случае `WPF`

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            // Здесь пишите код, который получает доступ к контролу
        }
```