# С# передача данных с COM порта на форму

Tags: c#, делегаты

Есть класс IKS1A, в нём идёт работа с COM портом через класс SerialPort. При приёме определённого количества байт срабатывает событие SerialPort.DataRecived b вызывается метод IKS1A.DoUpdate

```
 private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e) {
        byte[] rx_buf = new byte[16];
        SerialPort int_port = (SerialPort)s;
        int_port.Read(rx_buf, 0, 16);
        answer_measure_long answer;
        answer = BuffToStruct<answer_measure_long>(rx_buf);
        result_long_measure = answer.result;
        timeout = answer.timeout;

        UpdateST();
        if (timeout <= 0 || result_long_measure<0)
            Port.DataReceived -= DoUpdate;

    }
```

UpadateST- делегат класса IKS1A. Я думал через него передать на форму сообщение о том, что данные приняты и их можно отображать.

> UpdateST += Update;

Но при вызове UpdateST выходит исключение, попытка вызова Form1 не из того потока, в котором он был создан.

Подскажите как правильно передавать событие приёма данных в классе IKS1A на форму?

Comment: WinForms? Как вариант, нужно использовать [InvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx). Также смотрите [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx) и [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/Работа-с-контролами-из-фонового-потока).