# Обработка исключения InvalidOperationException (Windows Forms, C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

Вот стал вроде как простой вопрос.
Необходимо в windows forms получить изображение из видео потока. Изображение должно выводиться не полноразмерным, а только его выбранная часть, каждый раз его координаты могут изменяться. Для этого я на `panel` бросил `pictureBox`, в `panel` включил автоскрол, на `pictureBox` включил `autosize`. При запуске программы и загрузке изображения в `pictureBox` выдаёт сообщение:

Необработанное пользовательское исключение
`System.InvalidOperationException`: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления `panel1` не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Такая же ситуация происходит и при работе с обычным изображением, загружаешь и опять то же сообщение.

Как обработать это исключение, чтобы не выбивало постоянно это сообщение?
Если это проще простого делается - извините, в программировании ещё зелен, а некоторые задачи уже нужно решать.

Comment: Похоже что поток, вызвавший элемент для работы, закрывает доступ для других потоков

Comment: как тогда в этом случае быть? завершать каким-то образом поток?

Comment: возможно стоит поискать методы асинхронного доступа к объекту. Но к сожалению всех экстрасенсов вывезли из страны, без кода сказать ничего нельзя, добавьте в вопрос пример кода, где поток работает с изображением и понимание вашей проблемы будет более доступно для других

Comment: [InvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx), [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx), [руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx), [ответ на ru.so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/184217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов элемента управления из каких-либо других потоков, за исключением потока, в котором был создан элемент управления, без использования метода Invoke является нарушением безопасности.

При изменении элемента управления из другого потока (не владельца контрола) кидается InvalidOperationException.

Помещая код внутрь Control.Invoke(Delegate) вы сразу выполняете его в потоке, создавшем Control. А помещая внутрь Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate) код выполняется выполняется ассинхронно, т.е. вы не тратите время на ожидание окончания отработки кода.

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Это тест")));
```

Как видите, я даже вывод обычного диалога вставил в виде BeginInvoke, т.к. даже такой невинный вызов может вызвать InvalidOperationException, если его выполнять не в основном потоке GUI.

Comment: спасибо, очень доступно разъяснили!) буду пробовать это использовать у себя