# C#: Вызов функции основного потока, изменяющей содержимое контролов из другого потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть форма, которая открыта в основном потоке.

В ней вызывается другая форма, но она открывается в новом потоке.

Из этой новой формы вызывается метод другого класса, который изменяет содержимое RichTextBox той форме, в которой вызывался метод.

Ошибка: Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'richTextBox1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Вот код функции, которая изменяет содержимое RichTextBox:

```
public void writeLog(string word, RichTextBox logBox)
{
        logBox.SelectionStart = logBox.TextLength;
        logBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        logBox.SelectionColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        logBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + voids.GetTimeNow());
        logBox.SelectionColor = logBox.ForeColor;
        logBox.AppendText(word);
        logBox.SelectionStart = logBox.Text.Length;
        logBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Вот вызов той функции:

```
private Voids voids = Voids.GetInstance();
voids.writeLog("Какой то текст", richTextBox1);
```

А вот так открывается форма в новом потоке:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                NewForm();
            }).Start();
}
void NewForm()
{
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: А какой вопрос отмечен как источник для дубликата?

Comment: @VladD вот этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Ну всё правильно, дубликат. Вам нужно переброситься в исходный поток. Async/await не подойдёт, т. к. вы стартуете не в том контексте, а `BeginInvoke` самое оно.

Comment: @VladD, `BeginInvoke` на чём? Он же создаёт новую форму. Что-то мне кажется, тут другая проблема.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну он хочет из второго UI-потока доступиться к первому. «Из этой новой формы вызывается метод другого класса, который изменяет содержимое RichTextBox той форме, в которой вызывался метод.» Соответственно нужно писать ричТекстБоксМоейБабушкиОдин.БегинИнвоке(...).

Comment: @VladD, погоди. А new Form из другого потока - это точно нормально? И ShowDialog относительно чего её модальной будет делать?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну вроде норм, ShowDialog запускает собственный цикл сообщений. Ну а модальной относительно ничего, думаю :)

Comment: @Behavior перечитайте ответ по ссылке, попробуйте применить его к своему коду. Если результат не заработает, или что-то не получится - отредактируйте вопрос и приведите новый код  - его переоткроют и кто-нибудь вам ответит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что доступ к элементам управления может осуществляться только из потока, в котором он был создан. Если вы хотите получить доступ к элементу управления из другого потока, то можете использовать пару методов BeginInvoke и EndInvoke, здесь можно почитать об  этом [здесь можно почитать об  этом](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/thread_and_files/1/1_2.php)

Также вы можете использовать паттерн async/await.

И еще, лучше используйте объекты System.Threading.Tasks.Task для выполнения задач из другого потока, это позволит CLR более правильно управлять потоками.

Comment: Топикастеру уже дали такой же (и даже более подробный) ответ , в виде отметки дубликата https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/

Comment: @PashaPash разве можно дать ответ на вопрос уже отмеченный дубликатом?

Comment: @FoggyFinder нет, но топикастер удалил свой ответ и запостил его заново (без изменений). Ему об этом явно написали в комментариях, вопросы слили - но на "новый" вопрос успели ответить в стиле "здесь можно почитать об этом" :(

Comment: @FoggyFinder кстати, Delgate.BeginInvoke/EndInvoke, на который сослался автор ответа, не имеют **никакого отношения** к  Control.BeginInvoke, которым решается проблема из вопроса :). Как и упомянутые Task - они тоже ничем топикастеру не помогут.

Comment: @PashaPash Во-первых, Delegate.BeginInvoke или Control.BeginInvoke это не столь принципиально, я просто дал направление автору вопроса. Во-вторых, async/await автору **могут** помочь в этом вопросе - по сути трушный async/await завязан на EAP.

Comment: @AndreiS.в каком смысле "не столь принципиально"? Там из общего - только название метода. Статья по ссылке не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Т.е. направление вы дали, но это направление вникуда :)). Да, вы упомянули async/await. Но вы читали вопрос/ответ, на который завернули вопрос автора? Как вы думаете, в том ответе упомянуты Control.BeginInvoke и async/await?

Comment: @AndreiS.т.е. не подумайте что я ворчу, но в вашем ответе отношение к вопросу имеет только "вы можете использовать паттерн async/await". А это тянет максимум на комментарий. Т.е. вы вообще ни в чем не виноваты - просто автор вопроса решил не читать ссылку на дубликат в своем первом вопросе, и просто запостил его второй раз. Но тем не менее - стоит обращать внимание на комменты под вопросом, особенно если там есть упоминание дубликата - на многие стандартные вопросы на сайте уже есть развернутые ответы.

Comment: @PashaPash Тот вопрос, на который завернули поставлен четко, поэтому на него можно дать  четкий ответ, здесь же не совсем понятно, что у автора вообще происходит, ясно только, что где-то он допускает обращение к контролу для изменения из другого потока. И да, я посмотрел вопрос, на который завернули текущий, и, разумеется там упоминается и async/await и Begin/EndInvoke. Да, я пропустил этот комментарий, и я хотел оставить свой ответ в виде комментария, но на тот момент у меня еще не было достаточно очков репутации для этого. Я согласен, что на полноценный ответ это конечно не тянет :)

Comment: @AndreiS.если у автора непонятно что происходит - ставьте на вопрос тревогу соответствующего типа - вопрос закроют пока автор не принесет достаточно кода для воспроизведения