# c# Как вызвать метод "textBox" в windows forms из другого потока чтобы прокрутить в конец списка

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Имеется "textBox" (многострочный), заполняется сообщениями из "serialPort" и при добавлении новых строк прокручивается вверх (как уже все знают). 
Знаю что исправляется это методами

```
   textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
   textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
   textBox1.Refresh();
```

Но у меня многопоточность и прямое обращение к форме созданной в другом потоке "не безопасно". Для вызова метода "textBox.Text" есть специальный способ с применением "invoke" и delegate. 
Надеюсь что для вызова других его методов тажке есть способ, однако я так и не нашел его.

Я применил хитрость (глупость) и вызвал "прокрутку списка" по событию `textBox1_TextChanged()`, но тогда текст прыгает вверх и вниз как безбашенный, сперва прокручиваясь вверх по принятию новой строки, а потом вниз по событию "text changed". 
**UPDATE:** Оказалось что список скачет как бешеный во всех случаях при использовании способа `textBox.Text += "something";` и постоянно печатающегося текста.

Решение этой проблемы в использовании другого способа печатать в textBox: `textBox.AppendText("something");`

, а если вам нужна новая строка то: `textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);`
этот метод автоматически прокручивает "textBox" в конец текста
Этот метод быстрее и намного стабильнее (как я заметил).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace factyWinDBIntrf01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Thread readingThread;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getAvailPorstList();

        }

        void getAvailPorstList()
        {
            String[] portsList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            selectCOMPort.Items.AddRange(portsList);
        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text += serialPort1.ReadLine();
                textBox1.Text += "\n";
            }


            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Receive Timeout";
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (selectCOMPort.Text == "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "COM Port is not selected";
                }

                else if (comboBox1.Text == "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "Baud rate is not set";
                }

                else
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = selectCOMPort.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    progressBar1.Value = 100;
                    textBox1.Enabled = true;
                    textBox2.Enabled = true;
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    button3.Enabled = true;
                    selectCOMPort.Enabled = false;
                    button4.Enabled = false;
                    button5.Enabled = true;

                    readingThread = new Thread(readSerial);
                    readingThread.Start();
                }
            }

            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            { textBox1.Text = "Unauthorized Access"; }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readingThread.Abort();
            serialPort1.Close();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            selectCOMPort.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        }

        void readSerial()
        {
            while (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    {
                        textBox1_TextSafe(serialPort1.ReadLine());
                        textBox1_TextSafe("\n");
                        //DOESN'T WORK FOR MULTITHREAD CODE
                        //textBox1.Text += serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        //textBox1.Text += "\n";
                    }
                }

                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "Receive Timeout";
                }
                //not needed //Tread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }

        delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(string text);

        private void textBox1_TextSafe(string text)
        {
            if(textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                StringArgReturningVoidDelegate d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(textBox1_TextSafe);
                Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
               //-1@ NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS I GUESS
                //textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
               // textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                //textBox1.Refresh();
            }

           else
            {
                textBox1.Text += text;
                //-1@ AND THIS 
                //textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                //textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                //textBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //-2@ STUPID IDEA
            //textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            //textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            //textBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
textBox.Invoke(new Action(() =>{
    // делайте все, что вам нужно сделать в UI
}));
```

Comment: О, спасибо вы показали мне еще один способ использовать invoke, однако текст, опять, скачет как бешенный, то вверх то вниз.

Comment: Вы знаете , тут я решил проверить все в одном потоке. Все зависло как я ожидал и (к моему удивлению) текст, также, скачет как бешенный, при условии, если данные приходят постоянно.

Comment: @Faig Я вам показал, как запустить код в UI потоке. А почему у вас текст скачет я не представляю. Логгируйте ваши вызовы, исследуйте, что происходит в вашем коде.

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощ! А проблему с прыгающим текстом я решил при помощи "textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);" Он сам вставляет новую строку и прокручивает в конец текста.

Comment: @Faig Пожалуйста, рад что помогло