# Не добавляется элемент в List(of Custom Class) из функции webcontrol.WebView.BeforeRequestLoad

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не добавляется элемент в List(of Custom Class) из 
функции webcontrol.WebView.BeforeRequestLoad

```
 Private Sub Captcha_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        webcontrol = New WebControl
        webcontrol.WebView = New WebView
        webcontrol.WebView.Engine = engine
        webcontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Panel1.Controls.Add(webcontrol)
        webcontrol.WebView.LoadHtml("http://google.com")
        Form1.UC_tasks1.CaptchaKeysList.Add(New CaptchaKey("Test1", 10))
        AddHandler webcontrol.WebView.BeforeRequestLoad, AddressOf BeforeRequestLoad
    End Sub

    Public Sub BeforeRequestLoad(sender As Object, e As BeforeRequestLoadEventArgs)
                Form1.UC_tasks1.CaptchaKeysList.Add(New CaptchaKey("Test", 10))
    End Sub

    Public Class CaptchaKey
    Public Key As String
    Public Time As Integer
    Sub New(Key As String, Time As Integer)
        Me.Key = Key
        Me.Time = Time
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Зеленым работает, красным - нет

Comment: Код стоит приводить в виде кода, а не в виде скриншота. Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и посмотрите что происходит - может быть у вас обработчик вообще не вызывается, или один из IF внутри не срабатывает.

Comment: Все срабатывает и If тоже

Comment: Скорее всего BeforeRequestLoad вызывается в фоновом потоке (правда, тогда ваш код должен бросать ошибку, а не просто не работать). Оберните работу с контролами в Invoke: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/

Comment: PashaPash, видимо отладка не показывает ошибку, потому что переменная то общая, но тогда непонятно почему не добавляется в list(of ), спасибо, инвок сработал)

Comment: Запостил как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, Событие BeforeRequestLoad вызывается в фоновом потоке, из которого нельзя работать с контролами на форме.

Оберните работу с `Form1.UC_tasks1.CaptchaKeysList` в вызов `Form1.Invoke`.