# Доступ к контролу из другого потока

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть реализация класса купюроприемника(dll). Я читаю его статус и хочу на форме выводить его в TextBox.
После чтения статуса я хочу вызвать событие в котором и записать в TextBox значение.

```
public event EventHandler GetStatus;
```

......

```
    public async Task StartCommunication()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => StartProccess(token), token);
    }

    private void StartProccess(CancellationToken token)
    {
        byte resultStatus;
        resultStatus = Reset();
        Task.Delay(200);
        resultStatus = SetSequrity();
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            resultStatus = StatusRequest();
            OnGetStatus(new BillEventArgs(resultStatus));

            Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }
```

....

```
protected void OnGetStatus(BillEventArgs e)
        {
            GetStatus?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

На форме делаю так

```
private async void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bill.GetStatus += Bill_GetStatus;
            await bill.StartCommunication();
        }

        private void Bill_GetStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var eventArg = e as BillEventArgs;
            textBox3.Text = eventArg.Status.ToString();
        }
```

но при возникновении события вылетает ошибка на строке

```
textBox3.Text = eventArg.Status.ToString();
```

`System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'textBox3' не из того потока, в котором он был создан`

Как правильно организовать доступ к контролам на форме в такой ситуации?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/Работа-с-контролами-из-фонового-потока

Comment: @Philippe чем похоже? Там инициатор из UI потока, тут инициатор из не UI потока,

Comment: @tym32167 тут инициатор тоже из UI потока (обратите внимание на StartCommunication)

Comment: @PavelMayorov хмм, это я пропустил

Comment: @Philippe сорри, поторопился

Comment: @gregor обратите внимание на использование IProgress в ответе по приведенной вам ссылке...

Comment: @PavelMayorov А разве StartProcess не выполняется в другом потоке? Об этом собственно и говорит ошибка

Comment: @gregor в упомянутом ответе по ссылке тоже есть код который выполняется в другом потоке. Говорю же, посмотрите как там используется IProgress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для доступа к контролу из другого потока можно использовать `Form.Invoke()` - этот метод выполняет указанный делегат в том потоке, в котором была создана форма. Например, так:

```
private void Bill_GetStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var eventArg = e as BillEventArgs;
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        textBox3.Text = eventArg.Status.ToString();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Да, так и сделал. Получилось. Спасибо!