# Добавление данных в список привязанный к DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, datagridview

Вот так добавляю данные

```
public BindingList<Contract> Contracts = new BindingList<Contract>();
 public void AddContract(BinaryContract contract)
        {
            Contracts.Add(contract);
        }
```

Модель

```
    public class Contract : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _id { get; set; }
    private DateTime _openDate { get; set; }
    private string _currency { get; set; }
    private string _duration { get; set; }
    private string _operation { get; set; }
    private decimal _purchase { get; set; }
    private string _result { get; set; }
    private decimal _approximatePrice { get; set; }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public DateTime OpenDate
    {
        get { return _openDate; }
        set
        {
            _openDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Currency
    {
        get { return _currency; }
        set
        {
            _currency = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Duration
    {
        get { return _duration; }
        set
        {
            _duration = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Operation
    {
        get { return _operation; }
        set
        {
            _operation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public decimal Purchase
    {
        get { return _purchase; }
        set
        {
            _purchase = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Result
    {
        get { return _result; }
        set
        {
            _result = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public decimal ApproximatePrice
    {
        get { return _approximatePrice; }
        set
        {
            _approximatePrice = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Program.cs

```
namespace Presentation
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                IUnityContainer UnityC, UnityClogin;

                UnityC =
                    new UnityContainer()
                    .RegisterType<IMainView, MainView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMainPresenter, MainPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAboutPresenter, AboutPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAboutView, AboutView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ISettingsPresenter, SettingsPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ISettingsView, SettingsView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITelegram, Telegram>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITelegramService, TelegramService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMetaTrader, MetaTrader>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMetaTraderService, MetaTraderService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IProgramm, Programm>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IProgrammService, ProgrammService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())                 
                    .RegisterType<ITradeHistoryView, TradeHistoryView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITradeHistoryPresenter, TradeHistoryPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IContracts, Contracts>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IContractsService, ContractsService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

                UnityClogin =
                    new UnityContainer()
                    .RegisterType<IProgramm, Programm>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IProgrammService, ProgrammService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ILoginView, LoginView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ILoginPresenter, LoginPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAuthorizationUser, AuthorizationUser>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                IMainPresenter mainPresenter = UnityC.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
                IMainView mainView = mainPresenter.GetMainView();

                ILoginPresenter loginPresenter = UnityClogin.Resolve<LoginPresenter>();
                ILoginView loginView = loginPresenter.GetLoginView();

                Application.Run((LoginView)loginView);
                if (loginView.IsAuthenticated)
                    Application.Run((MainView)mainView);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Fatal($"Ошибка при запуске основного источника кода, либо возврат из-за полученной ошибки. Подробнее: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Присоединяю список к DataGridView

```
 public void LoadData(BindingList<Contract> Contracts)
        {
            dataGridViewHistory.DataSource = Contracts;
        }
```

И выпадает ошибка.

> Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу
>   управления '' не из того потока, в котором он был создан

В итоге данные добавляются в список (если форма закрыта), и позже видно их редактирование в режиме Real-Time так как я использую BindingList и реализовал INotifyPropertyChanged, но именно отображение добавленных данных в Real-Time не происходит и программа вызывает ошибку, подскажите как мне решить эту проблему.

p.s. [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) я изучил вдоль и поперек и он совсем не похож на мою реализацию, так как я вызываю лишь один раз при открытии формы присоединение к DataSource вот таким способом `_tradeHistoryView.LoadData(_contracts.GetContracts());`
и потом просто выполняю

```
dataGridViewHistory.DataSource = Contracts;
```

Пробовал в модель добавлять SynchronizationContext
, падает с ошибкой на отсутствие компонента

```
private SynchronizationContext syncContext;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public BinaryContract()
        {
            syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }

        private string _id { get; set; }
        private DateTime _openDate { get; set; }
        private string _currency { get; set; }
        private string _duration { get; set; }
        private string _operation { get; set; }
        private decimal _purchase { get; set; }
        private string _result { get; set; }
        private decimal _approximatePrice { get; set; }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (syncContext != null)
                syncContext.Post(_=> PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)), null);
            else
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Я работаю с WinForm и паттерном MVP поэтому у меня все разложено по разным классам и я не могу реализовать все в одном месте как это было в похожем вопросе. Подскажите как мне решить эту проблему??

**UPD**

Реализация таска в Program.cs

```
namespace Presentation
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                IUnityContainer UnityC, UnityClogin;

                UnityC =
                    new UnityContainer()
                    .RegisterType<IMainView, MainView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMainPresenter, MainPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAboutPresenter, AboutPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAboutView, AboutView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ISettingsPresenter, SettingsPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ISettingsView, SettingsView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITelegram, Telegram>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITelegramService, TelegramService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMetaTrader, MetaTrader>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMetaTraderService, MetaTraderService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IProgramm, Programm>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IProgrammService, ProgrammService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMartingale, Martingale>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IMartingaleService, MartingaleService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITradeHistoryView, TradeHistoryView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ITradeHistoryPresenter, TradeHistoryPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IContracts, Contracts>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IContractsService, ContractsService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

                UnityClogin =
                    new UnityContainer()
                    .RegisterType<IProgramm, Programm>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IProgrammService, ProgrammService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ILoginView, LoginView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ILoginPresenter, LoginPresenter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAuthorizationUser, AuthorizationUser>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());              

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.RegisterInstance(new UIThreadWorker());

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var worker = container.Resolve<UIThreadWorker>();
                    var data = worker.PerformInUIThread(() => new BinaryContract());
                    var wnd = worker.PerformInUIThread(() => container.Resolve<Contracts>());

                    worker.PerformInUIThread(() => wnd.AddContract(data));
                });

                IMainPresenter mainPresenter = UnityC.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
                IMainView mainView = mainPresenter.GetMainView();

                ILoginPresenter loginPresenter = UnityClogin.Resolve<LoginPresenter>();
                ILoginView loginView = loginPresenter.GetLoginView();

                Application.Run((LoginView)loginView);
                if (loginView.IsAuthenticated)
                    Application.Run((MainView)mainView);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Fatal($"Ошибка при запуске основного источника кода, либо возврат из-за полученной ошибки. Подробнее: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form (HistoryView)

```
public event EventHandler TradeHistoryViewLoadEventRaised;
        BindingList<BinaryContract> data;
        private DataGridView dg;

        public TradeHistoryView()
        {
            BeforeInitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent();
            dg = new DataGridView() { Height = 500 };
            this.Controls.Add(dg);
        }

        #region Common
        public void ShowTradeHistoryView()
        {
            ShowDialog();
        }

        private void BeforeInitializeComponent()
        {
            FormHelper.SetDialogAppearance(this);
        }

        private void TradeHistoryView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHelpers.RaiseEvent(this, TradeHistoryViewLoadEventRaised, e);
        }

        public void LoadData(BindingList<BinaryContract> binaryContracts)
        {
            data = binaryContracts;
            dg.DataSource = data;
        }
```

И класс Contracts неизменный

```
 public BindingList<BinaryContract> BinaryContracts = new BindingList<BinaryContract>();

        public void AddContract(BinaryContract contract) => BinaryContracts.Add(contract);
```

Comment: `Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { dataGridViewHistory.DataSource = Contracts }));` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Уже пробовал похожий способ, но падает то вот здесь  Contracts.Add(contract);

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: это означает, что Contracts вам также надо создавать в UI потоке

Comment: @tym32167 но к классу Contracts я не могу применить Invoke

Comment: @tym32167 похожий способ аналогично вызывает ошибку  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Contracts.Add(contract);
            });

Comment: А где, в каком классе он у вас создается? И вам точно нужен именно `BindingList`?

Comment: Я же указал на дубликат - почитайте его и поймете в чем проблема

Comment: @tym32167 я уже читал этот вопрос, к сожалению там нет решения моего вопроса, т.к. там выполняется все в одном потоке формы. Я же сначала с одной формы записываю значение в этот класс, как показано выше public BindingList<Contract> Contracts = new BindingList<Contract>(); и потом просто редактирую или добавляю. При редактировании созданных данных все отображается(если запустить форму после добавления), но именно при добавлении вываливается ошибка. BindingList как раз посоветовали для поддержки связи со списком

Comment: @tym32167 Вот этот код прекрасно отрабатывает если значение уже было добавлено и форма открыта после добавления {
            Contracts.First(x => x.Id == contract.Id).ApproximatePrice = contract.ApproximatePrice;
           Contracts.First(x => x.Id == contract.Id).Result = contract.Result;
        }

Comment: @tym32167 добавил еще описания в вопрос, мои данные привязываются а не вызываются как ReportProgress поэтому это совсем два разных решения

Comment: так вы создаете класс Contracts в другой форме? Обе формы работают в одном и том же потоке? Создание вашего Contracts происходит в UI потоке?

Comment: вы должны понимать, что работа с UI элементами (создание/изменение) должна происходить только в UI потоке. Ваше исключение `Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках` говорит о том, что вы список создали в одном потоке, а менять его пытаетесь в другом - в этом, собственно, и проблема

Comment: @tym32167 а почему тогда проходит редактирование а именно на добавлении валится ошибка?Как только выполняется функция редактирования я в DataGridView вижу изменения.

Comment: @tym32167 Я могу фактически отказаться от привязки через DataSource и просто таймером вызывать данные из списка и обновлять таблицу, но при имеющемся функционале я думаю это извращение...

Comment: редактирование происходит нормально по одной из двух причин: либо вы редактируете в UI потоке, либо вы редактируете не UI элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто как пример работы того. что вы делаете. 
 Создадим форму, на форме будет гррид и кнопка для добавления элемента. Создание списка с данными и добавление элемента в него выполним в UI потоке

```
class MyF : Form
{
    public class Item { public int Id { get; set; } }
    public BindingList<Item> Data;

    public MyF()
    {
        var dg = new DataGridView() { Height = 500 };
        var bt = new Button() { Text = "Add item", Left = 250 };

        bt.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Data.Add(new Item() { Id = Data.Count });
        };

        this.Load += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Data = new BindingList<Item>();
            dg.DataSource = Data;
        };  

        this.Controls.Add(dg);
        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Как видно, и добавление и изменение элемента работает без проблем.

**UPD**

Допустим, мы напишем воркер, который может запускать действия в UI потоке.

```
public class UIThreadWorker
{
    System.Windows.Application _app;
    public UIThreadWorker()
    {
        _app = new System.Windows.Application();
    }

    public void PerformInUIThread(Action act)
    {
        _app.Dispatcher.Invoke(act);
    }

    public T PerformInUIThread<T>(Func<T> act)
    {
        return _app.Dispatcher.Invoke(act);
    }
}
```

Наше окно теперь само не создает список, но есть возможность установить этот список внешнему коду

```
public class Item { public int Id { get; set; } }

class MyF : Form
{
    private BindingList<Item> Data;
    private DataGridView dg;

    public void SetData(BindingList<Item> data)
    {
        Data = data;
        dg.DataSource = Data;
    }

    public MyF()
    {
        dg = new DataGridView() { Height = 500 };
        var bt = new Button() { Text = "Add item", Left = 250 };

        bt.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Data?.Add(new Item() { Id = Data.Count });
        };

        this.Controls.Add(dg);
        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```

Что это изменило? Теперь мы можем создавать UI элементы и манипулировать ими в UI потоке при помощи нашего воркера. В примере ниже мы проинициализируем контейнер и воркер в одном потоке, а операции над UI контролами будем проксировать из другого потока в UI поток.

```
async Task Main()
{   
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterInstance(new UIThreadWorker());

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var worker = container.Resolve<UIThreadWorker>();
        var data = worker.PerformInUIThread(() => new BindingList<Item>());
        var wnd = worker.PerformInUIThread(() => container.Resolve<MyF>());

        worker.PerformInUIThread(() => wnd.SetData(data));
        worker.PerformInUIThread(() => wnd.ShowDialog());
    });
}
```

Результат аналогичный первой гифке.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83079/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167-------datagr).

Answer (score 1):

При работе с интерфейсом из других потоков, надо вызывать обновления данных в UI контролах от UI потока родителя, вот пример класса для `WinForm`

```
public class UIThreadSafe
{
    public static void Run(Form frm, Action act)
    {
        if (frm == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (frm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            frm.BeginInvoke(act);
        }
        else
        {
            act();
        }
    }
}
```

и вызывать примерно таким образом:

```
 UIThreadSafe.Run(this, (Action)(() => this.flatAlertBoxMain.ShowControl(...)));
```