# Обращение к элементу WindowsForms из статического метода, выполняющегося в другом потоке

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Всем доброго времени суток.
Поставлена задача написать широковещательный чат на UDP, используя Windows Forms, на C#. Создается глобальный поток:

```
Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
```

Метод ReceiveMessage - статический:

```
private static void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        UdpClient receiver = new UdpClient(localPort); // UdpClient для получения данных
        receiver.JoinMulticastGroup(remoteAddress, 20);
        IPEndPoint remoteIp = null;
        string localAddress = LocalIPAddress();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data = receiver.Receive(ref remoteIp);
                //if (remoteIp.Address.ToString().Equals(localAddress))
                //    continue;
                string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            receiver.Close();
        }
    }
```

Необходимо, чтобы при получении сообщения оно выводилось в ListBox. К сожалению, на данный момент единственный рабочий вариант - использовать MessageBox, а это совсем не то.
Заранее добавлю, что программа должна работать на .NET Framework 4, а лучше 3.5.
Знаю, что нужно копать в сторону асинхронных потоков, но сам пока не сумел встать на верный путь, поэтому прошу помощи здесь.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: хорошо, а в чем вопрос?

Comment: А зачем тут статичный метод? Делайте его обычным, инициализируйте этот класс (если это в отдельном классе) в Form1 (или что там у вас) и через конструктор передавайте ссылку на саму Form1.

Comment: @tym32167 из статического метода, работающего в отдельном потоке, нельзя обратиться к элементам формы

Comment: @EvgeniyZ все реализуется в пределах одного класса Form1

Comment: Так вопрос тот же, зачем тут статик?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage) не может обращаться к нестатическому методу

Comment: очень даже может, если создавать его не в инициализаторе, а. например, в конструкторе

Comment: Хорошо, с методом разобрались. Теперь вопрос с потоками, потому что при попытке что-то записать в listBoxt из метода, работающего в отдельном потоке (ReceiveMessage), выдает exception: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'listBox1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Comment: А это уже коллега, [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я уже писал ранее: "Знаю, что нужно копать в сторону асинхронных потоков, но сам пока не сумел встать на верный путь". Данную тему видел, но как-то реализовать асинхронность не смог

Comment: При чем тут асинхронность? Берете и пишете `listBox1.BeginInvoke...`. Читать только верх темы - не есть хорошо...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хотите верьте, хотите нет, но я читал всю тему, и дошел до Вашего решения только что (буквально за несколько секунд до Вашего ответа). В любом случае, спасибо, все работает.

Comment: В таком случае, вопрос решен.