# Изменить тип потока на STA

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Есть задача выполнить длительную по времени операция с контролом (WPF), дабы она не блокировала UI решил подсмотреть вариант [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0). По итогу вышел вот такой метод

```
async void PrintMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => messageView.PrintDirect(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Ошибка печати: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Однако, получаю ошибку следующего содержания: "Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA, поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов UI".
Если бы я создавал поток с использованием `Thread`, я бы использовал метод `SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`, а вот что делать в таком случае я не знаю. Есть какие-нибудь вариаты?

Comment: Создавайте поток руками и устанавливайте ему все, что надо

Comment: Если создам руками, то для работы этого метода придется завернуть его в `Dispatcher.Invoke()` и все равно UI будет заблокирован

Comment: зачем это заворачивать в Dispatcher.Invoke?

Comment: потому что `messageView` - элемент UI, доступ к нему из фонового потока не получить без использования `Dispatcher` того же потока, в котором он был создан, следовательно, и вся операция будет выполняться в основном GUI-потоке и все встанет колом, пока не выполнится

Comment: Решение по ссылке - это не "легкий способ сделать, чтобы всегда не блокировался UI". Он предполагает, что "SomeLongOperation" не взаимодействует с UI.

Comment: пфф, тогда вам `Task.Factory.StartNew` не поможет по тем же самым причинам

Comment: мм, допустим, а есть ли вариант, не блокируя интрефейс, в моем случае выполнить долгий метод?

Comment: У вас противоречие в самом вопросе. "Длительная операция с контролом" никак не может "не блокировать UI поток". Разделяйте UI и данные и используйте разные потоки.

Comment: смысл этой операции не подразумевает разделения данных и UI, потому что операция - печать содержимого таблицы, с учетом всего внешнего вида. И это внутренний метод контрола.

Comment: Тогда вам придётся работать в UI-потоке. Подключайте `Dispatcher`. Разбивайте ваш метод печати на мелкие части и выполняйте их последовательно как `DispatcherOperation` через `Dispatcher` UI-потока, при этом не забывая давать `Dispatcher`у выполнять другие операциии, чтобы UI не выглядел зависшим.

Comment: если вам надо провести долгую операцию с контролами, вы можете попробовать это делать в отдельном окне, чтобы не мешать контролы между потоками

Comment: @tym32167, у другого окна будет тот же `Dispatcher` и тот же UI-поток (если специально не создавать окно с другим `Dispatcher` и в другом потоке - но в этом случае контрол нельзя будет "перетащить" из первого окна во второе во время выполнения).

Comment: @dymanoid я про это и говорю, другое окно, другой поток, другой диспетчер, и не шарить контролы, чтобы тормоза во втором окне не задевали основное приложение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу я решил свою проблему следующим способом:

1. Создал окно WPF с разметкой из одного требуемого мне контрола - полной копией того, что в основном окне.
2. Создание этого окна сделал в отдельном потоке, отображал окно с помощью `ShowDialog()` так как он не дает потоку завершиться раньше времени.

   `Thread hidePrintThread = new Thread(PrintMethod);
       hidePrintThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       hidePrintThread.IsBackground = true;
       hidePrintThread.Start();`

   ```
   void PrintMethod()
       {
           try
           {
               CriteriaOperator co=null;
               List<MessageGridContent> mess = Service.Messages.ToList();
               Dispatcher.Invoke(() => co = messageGrid.FilterCriteria);
               HiddenPrintWindow window = new HiddenPrintWindow();
               window.MessagesToPrint = mess;
               window.CriteriaOperator = co;
               Service.Printing = true;
               window.ShowDialog();                
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               logger.Error("Ошибка печати: {0}", ex.Message);
           }
       }
   ```
3. Так как мне необходимо было, чтобы данная длительная операция проходила незаметно для пользователя, я решил скрыть окно. Стандартные методы работать отказывались. Я пробовал прописывать `Visibyliti` в разметке, пробовал в обработчике события загрузки окна, пробовал в методе, который запускается из обработчика загрузки, но окно упрямо висело видимым, тогда я убрал его на задний план (тоже подходило по ТЗ) с помощью WinAPI:

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);`

Код инициализации и загрузки самого окна:

```
public HiddenPrintWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            Loaded += HiddenPrintWindow_Loaded;
        }

private void HiddenPrintWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                SetWindowPos(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
                Work();
            }
```

И спасибо всем помогавшим!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно показать окно в отдельном потоке и при этом оно будет в режиме STA, да, в этом окне вам придется повторить свой контрол (т.к. просто перенести его на другую форму у вас не получится):

```
BusyWindow _busyWindow = null;

object _busyWindowSync = new object();

private void ShowBusy()
{
    lock (_busyWindowSync)
    {
        if (_busyWindow == null)
        {
            double left = Dispatcher.Invoke((Func<double>)(() => this.Left + this.Width / 2));
            double top = Dispatcher.Invoke((Func<double>)(() => this.Top + this.Height / 2));
            Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AnimationThreadStartingPoint));
            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
            newWindowThread.Start(new Point() { X = left, Y = top });
        }
    }
}

private void AnimationThreadStartingPoint(object position)
{
    lock (_busyWindowSync)
    {
        if (_busyWindow == null)
        {
            _busyWindow = new BusyWindow();
            _busyWindow.Left = ((Point)position).X;
            _busyWindow.Top = ((Point)position).Y;
            _busyWindow.Show();
        }
    }
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}

private void HideBusy()
{
    lock (_busyWindowSync)
    {
        if (_busyWindow != null)
        {
            _busyWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)_busyWindow.Close);
        }
    }
}
```

BusyWindow - это класс окна показываемого в отдельном потоке. Пример вот от [сюда](https://losev-al.blogspot.com/2015/08/blog-post.html), и там это окно использовалось для анимации, которую нельзя отобразить в основном окне. Вы, наоборот, можете в этом окне выполнять длительную операцию, чтобы не подвисало основное окно. Ну или прямо взять этот пример и пока у вас "висит" главное окно, пользователь будет видеть спиннер.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Свою проблему я частично решил с помощью создания в отдельном потоке обычного окна, в котором есть вся требуемая мне разметка. Но я столкнулся с проблемой того, что это окно должно быть невидимым, а оно никак не хочет нормально скрываться и при этом выполнять метод.

Comment: Что значит нормально скрываться и выполнять метод? При скрытом окне компонент не отрисовывается и вы не можете его вывести на печать?

Comment: Нет. Общая суть того, что я попытался реализовать: создается поток типа STA, в нем создается окно с разметкой, по событию `Loaded` для этого окна начинается выполнение долгой операции. Но первым делом в обработчике этого события я пытаюсь это дочернее окно сделать невидимым с помощью `Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`, но почему-то окно продолжает висеть видимым.

Comment: Разбейте метод на два. В лоадед оставьте только скрытие и запуск нового метода через Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: При использовании такого подхода фоновый поток заканчивается сразу после обработчика `Loaded` и основной метод не выполняется