# Как в MVS сделать правильную смену значения текстового поля?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        label1.Text = "Ждем";
        //тут - вычисления, занимающие несколько секунд
        label1.Text = "Готово";
}
```

После нажатия сначала думает, потом выводит запись "Готово", запись "Ждем" пропускается почему-то.

Как исправить?

Comment: "Ждем" не пропускается. Т.к. запускаешь в потоке вместе с UI у тебя блокируется вывод. Выход - использовать асинхронный запуск.

Comment: @Геннадий-П В Framework 2.0 это возможно сделать?

Comment: @Mart и даже в 1.0 )

Comment: @Mart [System.Threading](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading)

Comment: @Геннадий-П "using System.Threading.Tasks" не могу добавить даже в шапку.

Comment: @Mart Task с 4.0, используйте Thread. Т.е. запускайте в отдельном потоке, а не таске.

Comment: @Геннадий-П Я через "System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For" только работал, в 2.0 какая функция альтернативой является?

Comment: @Mart [вот тут](https://habr.com/post/126495/) все расписано простым языком

Comment: @Геннадий-П "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления "label1" не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Comment: @Mart [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) в конце "Решение для .NET 3.5 и более ранних версий"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях указано, что нужна реализация под .NET 2.0. В этой версии фреймворка нужно использовать `Thread`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Ждем";

    new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        // тут длительные вычисления

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Text = "Готово";
        });
    })
    .Start();
}
```

В данном примере создается и запускается (вызовом метода `Start`) отдельный поток. Длительные вычисления выполняются в нём. Тем временем gui-поток может спокойно отрисовывать контролы.

К контролам формы можно обращаться только из того потока, в котором они созданы. Для этого используем метод `Invoke`. Его вызов посылает сообщение в основной поток gui.

Примечание: внутри делегата `Invoke` выполняйте только обращение к gui-контролам, не делайте в нём никакие длительные операции.