# Как открыть модальное окно ShowDialog() в FrameWork 4.0? Исключение in PresentationCore.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста, разрабатываю приложение WPF под FrameWork 4.0, т.к. необходима совместимость с win XP. При определённом условии, мне необходимо вызвать модальное окно, но при всём богатстве описания данной процедуры - я терплю неудачу... получаю исключение: `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll` на вот этой строке : `Window_Dialog winDialog = new Window_Dialog();`

Ошибка вроде бы не новая, решения её есть, вызов во втором потоке, но скорее всего сказывается скудный опыт, ибо решить не получается.

```
void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Order result = orders.Find(x => x.Id == TempOrder.Id);

        if(result.CustomerName == "")
        {
            Window_Dialog winDialog = new Window_Dialog();

            if (winDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Записано!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Отмена");
            }

        }
}
```

Буду рад Вашему совету! Спасибо!

Comment: Полный текст ошибки приложите

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Полный текст ошибки :`Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll` Окно просто не открывается. В Output только эта строка

Comment: @MSDN, а разве нельзя создать окно в другом потоке? Вроде можно.

Comment: @Andrey, попробуйте вместо этого таймера использовать DispatcherTimer. Ну и я просил весь стектрейс показать

Comment: @АндрейNOP Можно. Но, во-первых, поток, на котором выполняется таймер, вряд ли запущен с атрибутом STAThread, а во-вторых, даже если создать окно в фоновом потоке получится, любое взаимодействие этого окна с другими окнами должно будет осуществляться через Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke. С высокой вероятностью, это не то, чего хочет автор.

Comment: @Андрей NOP, я попробовал переделал таймер на  `DispatcherTimer`, и всё заработало! Спасибо Вам! Буду рад отметить решением! По поводу логов, в 500 символов не уместился бы, но было как-то так: `'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: app.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationCore.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.` А потом строка, которую я Вам написал выше.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я посмотрел материал, по ссылке, что Вы написали, и он мне то же пригодиться, т.к. из диалогового окна необходимо будет возвращать выбранные пользователем значения, а там как раз на старые фреймворки! С ними, как я понял, одни нюансы... Спасибо! По поводу атрибута STAThread, я видел советы, но видать неумело применял, т.к. результат был 0. Спасибо Вам за советы!