# Как записывать данные в textbox из другого потока

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть задача: дано 3 потока, которые генерируют значения(0-9, 10-99, 100-250), которые записываются в общий массив, и выводятся на экран. Также нужно додавать их в сумму, которая должна находится в пределах от 11500 до 12500, числа при этом с массива удаляются..... Как мне отображать эти числа в `textbox`?

```js
List < int > numbers = new List < int > ();
int sum = 0;

public Second() {
  InitializeComponent();
  Task first = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateNumber(0, 9, FirstOutput));
  Task second = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateNumber(10, 99, SecondOutput));
  Task third = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateNumber(100, 200, ThirdOutput));
}

private void GenerateNumber(int low, int hight, TextBox textBox) {
  Random random = new Random();
  int number;
  while (true) {
    number = random.Next(low, hight);
    numbers.Add(number);
    textBox.Text = number.ToString();

    Task.Delay(200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте через invoke, пример функции:

```
public class ActionThreadSafe
    {
        public static void Run(Form frm, Action act)
        {
            if (frm == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (frm.InvokeRequired)
            {
                frm.BeginInvoke(act);
            }
            else
            {
                act();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Использоавание**

```
    ActionThreadSafe.Run(this, (Action)(() => this.Control.Text = "тест"));
```