# Проблема с потоками wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, таймер

Есть обычный **таймер** класса `Timer`. Каждый раз вызывается метод для отсчёта времени. И этот же метод вызывает другой метод, который обновляет значение часов в TextBox'е. Но тут всплывает ошибка:

`"System.InvalidOperationException: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."`

В интернете прочитал, что это связанно с тем что в wpf нельзя менять значение некоторых классов. **Но все найденные решения не подходят, так как у меня .NET 4.**

Как мне быть?

Comment: DispatcherTimer или Dispatcher. Первое - это тот же таймер, но события выполняются в UI потоке, в котором создан. Второе - это непосредственно диспетчер, через который можно вызывать методы в том же UI потоке.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с контролами из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему.

у каждого **UIЭлемнта** есть свойство `Dispatcher`. И уже у него есть пара методов `BeginInvoke` и `Invoke`, в которые нужно передать делегат не принимающий параметров. И уже в нём выполнять изменение wpf-элемента.

**Пример моего кода**

```
    private delegate void TimeOutput(); //Делегат, передаваемый в метод Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

    private void DecreaseTime(object obj)
    {
        //Уменьшаю таймер

        TimerOutputField.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new TimeOutput(OutputTimeLeft)); //TimerOutputField - имя моего TextBlock
    }
    // А этот метод используется в качестве экземпляра передаваемого делегата TimeOutput
    private void OutputTimeLeft()
    {
        TimerOutputField.Text = TimeLeft.ToString();
    }
```

*P.S* BeginInvoke и Invoke отличаются тем, что BeginInvoke выполняет работу асинхронно, а Invoke - синхронно