# Как отрисовать Usercontrol из async метода

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, асинхронность, usercontrol

Создаю сервер с таблицей, которая представляет собой usercontrol c именем Clientlist куда выводится информация о подключенных пользователях. При подключении к серверу, пользователь отправляет ему строку с информацией о себе (IP, имя компьютера) и на основе этой информации формируется строка в таблице. Строка представляет собой второй usercontrol. Clientlist имеет метод на добавление строки с информацией о пользователе

Все приведенные ниже действия происходят в классе Server

Сервер работает асинхронно и соответственно код выглядит примерно следующим образом:
Программа доходит до строчки с ожиданием прихода строки

```
Client client = new Client();
handler.BeginReceive( client.buffer, 0, client.buffer.length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), client);
```

Как только к серверу приходит строка с информацией вызывается метод ReadCallback

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
//Парс строки и заполнение полей класса Client
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
main.Clientlist.AddClient(client)
//...
}
```

Приведенный вариант метода ReadCallback, конечно работать не будет, сразу вылетит ошибка о том, что это не STA поток и так далее.

Вот соответственно встал вопрос о том как из метода ReadCallback я могу обратится к своему Clientlist и отрисовать информацию о клиенте на своей форме.

Comment: Вы не должны в WPF хотеть обращаться к контролу из кода! Отделите логику от интерфейса, используйте привязки, пишите все по правилам MVVM и тогда не будет у вас подобных проблем. Ну а так, это скорей всего [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418461)

Comment: Если  вам надо что то выполнить в UI потоке, то вы можете для этого использовать диспетчер. Например, `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`.