# Как исправить ошибку c HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, winforms, htmlagilitypack

Выдает ошибку:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа 
к элементу управления 'Plaintiffs' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."
```

---

В чем прикол?

Начало появляться после добавления `if(node != null)`, но мне это нужно, без него может появиться ошибка, что нету такого xpath'a.

Код:

```
using System;
using CefSharp;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using CefSharp.OffScreen;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private string html;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();

            browser.FrameLoadEnd += WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded;
        }


        private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("РАБОТАЕМ!");
                browser.ViewSource();
                browser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
                {
                    html = taskHtml.Result;
                    Parce();
                });
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Load($"https://kad.arbitr.ru/Card?number={textBox1.Text}");
        }

        private void InitializeChromium()
        {

            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://kad.arbitr.ru");
           // Controls.Add(browser);
           // browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void Parce()
        {
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
                HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='gr_case_partps']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/ul/li/span/a");
                if(node != null)
                {
                node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='gr_case_partps']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/ul/li/span/a");
                Plaintiffs.Text = "Истцы:\n" + node[0].InnerText.Replace(" ", ""); // ТУТ ОШИБКА

                node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='gr_case_partps']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/ul/li/span/a");
                defendant.Text = "Ответчики:\n" + node[0].InnerText.Replace(" ", "");

                node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='chrono_list_content']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/h4/span[2]/span/a");
                judje.Text = "Суд:\n" + node[0].InnerText.Replace(" ", "");
                }

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `browser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith` — а почему не `await`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418461/220553

Answer (score 2):

Это абсолютно никак не связанно с `if(node != null)`.

Вам выдаёт ошибку из-за того, что **вы пытаетесь присвоить текст контролу из другого потока** (вы вызываете функцию `Parse` в потоке, полученным от браузера).

Что бы исправить это, вы можете принудительно присвоить текст из нужного потока, а то-есть потока формы. Для этого нужно использовать метод `Invoke()` формы. Это можно сделать так:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => Plaintiffs.Text = "Истцы:\n" + node[0].InnerText.Replace(" ", "")));
```

Можно вынести это в отдельную функцию, например так:

```
private void SetTextToControl(Control control, string text)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => control.Text = text));
}
```

И затем использовать так:

```
SetTextToControl(Plaintiffs, "Истцы:\n" + node[0].InnerText.Replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: Лучше наверное использовать каст делегата вместо создания `new` экшна `this.Invoke((Action)(() => control.Text = text));`.

Comment: @aepot возможно, но я не думаю, что будет какая-то существенная разница