# Не могу запустить асинхронную функцию конвертации видео

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, асинхронность

пытаюсь запустить асинхронный метод конвертации, использую FFMpeg.Но при активации кнопки появляется ошибка "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."

Пробовал способы из интернета, но ничего не помогает. Я только новичок, если вопрос очень лёгкий, прошу прощения.

```
    public async void startConvert()
    {
        if (SaveValues.multiImportMode)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Process process1 = new Process();
            process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\ffmpeg-5.1-full_build\bin";
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + videoPathTextBox.Text + "\" -qscale 0 \"" + SaveValues.finalVideoPath + "\\ConvertedVideo" + CheckNameFinalVideo() + SaveValues.finalFormatVideo + "\"";
            process1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            process1.Start();

            Random ran = new Random();
            progressBar.Value = ran.Next(10, 75);
            while (true)
            {
                if (process1.HasExited)
                {
                    progressBar.Value = 100;
                    status.Text = "Done";
                    await Task.Delay(3000);
                    status.Text = "";
                    progressBar.Value = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async void applyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => startConvert());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я же вроде функцию так и запускаю, но всё равно ошибку выдаёт

Comment: Внимательней читайте, а не сразу комментируйте. Особенно внимание на `Решение с отображением прогресса выполнения`. Вы не должны в коде вообще использовать контролы, у вас должны быть свойства, к котором привязаны контролы, а метод наружу должен отдавать прогресс, который вы реализуете и через него меняете значение привязанных свойство. Сейчас вы просто дергаете вечно контролы по именам (`progressBar.Value` и `status.Text`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Извините, поторопился. Спасибо большое, всё заработало.