# Не удается преобразовать лямбда-выражение к типу "Delegate", так как он не является типом делегата

Tags: c#

```
public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  string indata = this.serialPort1.ReadExisting();
  this.Invoke((Delegate)(() => this.rtbserial.Text += indata));
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/220553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Превести к делегату это не значит приведение к типу `Delegate`, а к конкретному делегату. Чтобы создать конкретный тип делегата, можно его объявить, либо использовать совместимый с перегрузкой `Control.Invoke`, например `Action`.

Для старых фреймворков 4.x так

```
this.Invoke((Action)(() => this.rtbserial.Text += indata));
```

Для новых так

```
this.Invoke(() => this.rtbserial.Text += indata);
```