# Помогите "ускорить" потоки C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, многопоточность, threading

У меня есть задание:

Разработать многопоточное приложение, выполняющее следующие действия. Для каждого файла в директории построить массив из 256 элементов, содержащий количество значений байт, составляющих файл, т.е. нулевой элемент массива должен содержать количество байт в файле равных 0, первый элемент – кол-во байт равных 1 и т.д.

Соответственно, каждый файл должен обрабатываться отдельным потоком. Результаты вывести (+сохранить в текстовый файл) построчно для каждого обработанного файла, в порядке завершения обработки. Каждая строка должна содержать имя файла, потраченное на обработку время, результирующий массив (элементы через запятую).

В программе должны быть реализованы:

- выбор директории для обработки;
- вывод результатов на экран по мере обработки.

В процессе написания программы я сделал обычный (линейный способ без потоков) для проверки работы в целом, затем сделал потоковый способ.

До этого я ни разу не сталкивался с многопоточным программированием, поэтому получились КОСТЫЛИ.

Есть класс `FilesHandler`:

```
class FilesHandler{
            private List<string> PathesOfFiles = new List<string>(); //Содержит пути к файлам
            static object locker = new object();
            public void HandleEachFile(RichTextBox RTB) //обработчик каждого файла 
            {
                foreach (string path in PathesOfFiles)  
                {
                /*Вариант без потоков*/
                //CalculateNew(RTB, path);

                /*Вариант с потоками*/
                new Thread(() => { CalculateThread(RTB, path); }).Start();
                }
            }

            private void CalculateNew(RichTextBox RTB, string tmpPath)
            {
            RTB.Text += DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\t";
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); //Создаём секундомер
            stopwatch.Start(); //Запускаем секундомер
            Converter tmpobj = new Converter(); //Создаём объект "файла"
            tmpobj.CountBytes(tmpPath); //Метод, который читает файл поблочно и сразу обрабатывает блок(считает байты)
            List<string> res = new List<string>(); //создаём массив для результирующей строки
            res.Add(GetFileName(tmpPath)); //Записываем первым имя файла
            res.Add(" {");
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) //Переписываем кол-во каждого байта
            {
                if (i != 255)
                    res.Add(tmpobj.GetBytes()[i].ToString() + ", ");
                else
                    res.Add(tmpobj.GetBytes()[i].ToString() + "} ");
            }
            stopwatch.Stop(); //Останавливаем секундомер, чтобы записать время обработки файла
            res.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
            RTB.Text += String.Join("", res) + '\n'; //RTB - richtextbox как консоль для вывода информации
            }

            private void CalculateThread(RichTextBox RTB, string tmpPath) //Для варианта с потокам всё вынесено в отдельную функцию
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    Action action2 = () => RTB.Text += DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\t";
                    if (RTB.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        RTB.Invoke(action2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        action2();
                    }
                    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); //Создаём секундомер
                    stopwatch.Start(); //Запускаем секундомер
                    Converter tmpobj = new Converter(); //Создаём объект "файла"
                    tmpobj.CountBytes(tmpPath); //Метод, который читает файл поблочно и сразу обрабатывает блок(считает байты)
                    List<string> res = new List<string>(); //создаём массив для результирующей строки
                    res.Add(GetFileName(tmpPath)); //Записываем первым имя файла
                    res.Add(" {");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) //Переписываем кол-во каждого байта
                    {
                        if (i != 255)
                            res.Add(tmpobj.GetBytes()[i].ToString() + ", ");
                        else
                            res.Add(tmpobj.GetBytes()[i].ToString() + "} ");
                    }
                    stopwatch.Stop(); //Останавливаем секундомер, чтобы записать время обработки файла
                    res.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

                    Action action3 = () => RTB.Text += String.Join("", res) + '\n';
                    if (RTB.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        RTB.Invoke(action3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        action3();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Также есть класс `Converter`, в котором полем является `ulong[] Bytes = new ulong[256];` и метод (основной для объяснения), который считает вхождения байтов выбранного файла:

```
    public void CountBytes(string filename)
    {
        FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(filename);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                byte b = buffer[i];
                Bytes[b]++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Идея моей реализации такова:
в `foreach` при чтении пути каждого файла создается поток, который вызывает метод `CalculateThread`.

По сути же у меня каждый поток не имеет доступа к одному и тому же ресурсу, потому что объект `Converter` создается внутри метода, но без `lock` адекватно работать не будет, потому что на директории в 5гб работает молниеносно, нежели линейный способ, а если взять директорию на 50гб (с таким же кол-вом файлов), то серьезно отстает от линейного, а с `lock` +- одинаково, но дольше все равно.

Поток обрабатывает файлик, и потом сразу печатает в `richtextbox` результат.

Есть подозрения, что как раз из-за прерывания для записи результата эта задержка возникает.

UPD:

подскажите, пожалуйста, если делать с async await, это так должно выглядеть?

```
private async void Method(RichTextBox RTB, string path)
    {
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            new Thread(() => {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); //Создаём секундомер
                stopwatch.Start(); //Запускаем секундомер
                Converter tmpobj = new Converter(); //Создаём объект "файла"
                tmpobj.CountBytes(path); //Метод, который читает файл поблочно и сразу обрабатывает блок(считает байты)
                res.Add(String.Concat(GetFileName(path), " {", String.Join(", ", tmpobj.GetBytes()), "}")); // Join сам применяет ToString!
                stopwatch.Stop(); //Останавливаем секундомер, чтобы записать время обработки файла
                res.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
            }).Start();
        });
        RTB.Text += String.Join("", res) + '\n';
    }
```

Comment: Как ускорить работу потоков, чтобы был большой отрыв по времени от обычного способа????

Comment: Потоки вам не нужны, вам нужна асинхронность (`async/await`), да и вообще нынче потоки очень редко используют. Ну а вообще, я надеюсь вы осознаете тот факт, что вы ограничены возможностью диска? "дисковый ввод-вывод — по существу последовательная операция". То есть, создав вы хоть миллиард потоков, файлы будут считываться диском последовательно, только если это не какой либо RAID массив, где дисков несколько, и то там свои тонкости. Поэтому, ваша цель по разбитию чтения файлов с диска на множество потоков, немного бессмысленна. Делайте `Task`, пусть ждет действия от диска, но потоки...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я придерживался задания. Повторюсь, до этого с многопоточностью не работал и не знаю в каких ситуациях как лучше действовать. Спасибо за совет, попробую Task

Comment: Многопоточность при работе с диском категорически противопоказана, я бы сказал. Не дай бог HDD будет гонять головку туда-сюда.

Comment: Буфер нужно увеличить, совершенно точно. 4096 - это ничто. Тогда и от многопоточности может толк появиться. Нужно поэкспериментировать с размером буфера.

Comment: FileStream нужно закрывать, см. ответ.

Comment: Если нужно реальное ускорение, то  1) для чтения файлов надо использовать memory mapping, т.о. вы не будете пересылать данные из файлового кэша ОС в user space 2) количество потоков должно соответствовать не количеству файлов, а количеству ядер в процессоре, т.е. однажды запущенный поток обрабатывает несколько файлов 3) алгоритм должен быть таким, чтобы потоки во время работы не требовали синхронизации (mutex, semaphore и т.п.), т.е. области памяти с исходными данными и результатами работы потока нужно подготовить заранее. Тогда все заработает действительно быстро

Comment: @avp хочу уточнить п. 2. Это касается только чисто вычислительных задач. Если речь идёт о вводе-выводе, то на устройство нужно выделить один поток, а остальное согласно п. 2. Что можно распарралелить? Подсчёт байтов. Только, к сожалению, это самая быстрая часть задачи. Основное время занимает чтение файлов.

Comment: @rotabor, в целом, согласен, но тут есть системозависимая специфика. Для такой задачи теоретически  достаточно 2-х потоков (один инициирует чтение, второй подсчитывает уже скачанные с диска байты). Конечно, при таком подходе возникнут еще и дополнительные расходы на синхронизацию. Но, это без учета специфики оптимизации порядка операций IO в OS. Понятно, что последовательные запросы из разных процессов можно переупорядочивать, минимизируя перемещение головок диска ("лифт Линуса" в linux). Делает ли OS то же самое для запросов к разным файлам из одного процесса? Не знаю

Comment: Вам тут много всего написали, дальше уже давайте как-то сами. Или задавайте более конкретные вопросы. Можете так же поделиться результатами своей работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть над чем поработать:

```
    public void CountBytes(string filename)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // нужно завести один буфер, чтобы не тратить каждый вызов метода время на его создание
        // но это не для многопоточного варианта
        // 4096 - это ничто, нужно кратно увеличить, тогда и от многопоточности может толк появиться 
        int bytesRead = 0; // это тоже как бы лишнее, но ни на что не влияет
        using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(filename))
            while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; Bytes[buffer[i++]]++);
                // byte b = buffer[i]; - это лишнее, значение используется один раз.
                // и не факт, что будет оптимизировано
    }
```

Вместо этого

```
            res.Add(GetFileName(tmpPath)); //Записываем первым имя файла
            res.Add(" {");
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) //Переписываем кол-во каждого байта
            {
                if (i != 255)
                    res.Add(tmpobj.GetBytes()[i].ToString() + ", ");
                else
                    res.Add(tmpobj.GetBytes()[i].ToString() + "} ");
            }
```

написать

```
return String.Concat(
    GetFileName(tmpPath), " {"
    , String.Join(", ", tmpobj.GetBytes()) // Join сам применяет ToString!
    , "}");
```

Можно сделать обработку файла задачей

```
        string CalculateNew(string tmpPath) {
            var a = new byte[5] { 11, 34, 23, 56, 74 }; // это пример такой
            return String.Join(", ", a);
        }
    ...
    RTB.Text += DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\t";
    RTB.Text += Task.Run(() => CalculateNew(tmpPath)).Result) + "\t";
```

Comment: Мой куратор сказал удалить обращение к компонентам формы из потока и что можно обратный вызов сделать в компоненте потока, например
но я не понимаю, как это сделать

Comment: Разберёмся. Это нужно убрать от "Action action3 = ()..." и далее.

Comment: я исправил ваши замечания, кроме вывода "лога". Оставил только вычислительные процессы, где просто файл обрабатывается, но все равно по времени потоки не опережают обычный способ. Я уже просто с секундомером сижу и замеряю :))))

Comment: я отслеживаю работу потоков по их выполнению в "выводе", где пишется о завершении потока, но все равно потоки не быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Просто вкину альтернативный вариант.

Накпишем функцию, которая читает файл с буфером

```
private ulong[] GetBytesStats(string file)
{
    var ret = new ulong[256];
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    var len = 0;
    using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(file), 10 * 1024 * 1024))
        while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) ret[buffer[i]]++;
    return ret;
}
```

Перевод статистики в строку

```
private string ToString(ulong[] data)
{
    return string.Join(", ", data);
}
```

Метод, который обрабатывает файл и выводит его на консоль

```
private void ProcessFile(string file)
{   
    Console.WriteLine($"Stats for {file} = {ToString(GetBytesStats(file))}");   
}
```

запускаем метод параллельно

```
var files = new List<string>();
files.Add(@"C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png");
files.Add(@"C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png");
files.Add(@"C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png");
files.Add(@"C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png");
files.Add(@"C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png");
files.Add(@"C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png");
Parallel.ForEach(files, f=>ProcessFile(f));
```

Результат

```
Stats for C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png = ......
Stats for C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png = ......
Stats for C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png = ......
Stats for C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png = ......
Stats for C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png = ......
Stats for C:\Dev\Temp\some_file.png = ......
```

Можно это всё и асинхронно сделать - но это уже как домашнее задание.

Comment: у меня не консольное приложение, а оконное. В кастве "консоли" richtextbox. Из-за этого нужно прерывание для вывода инф-ии на richtextbox

Comment: Если уже умеете пробрасывать вызов в UI поток, то адаптировать пример под себя вам труда не составит

Comment: я делаю прерывание через action или это плохо пример?

Comment: 1) это называется проброс вызова в UI поток, а не прерывание. 2) action - это просто указатель на функцию, а не способ проброса вызова 3) Как правильно делать нписано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/179763), если вкратце, то `myRichTechBox.Invoke(....)`

Comment: я добавил изменения в вопросе, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: На ваш изначальный вопрос уже ответили. Если у вас новый вопрос - задавайте его отдельно. Вы не можете просто бесконечно менять вопрос, чтобы получить несколько ответов - иаче авторы ответов не получат свои плюсики. Потому придерживайтесь правила: 1 вопрос - 1 ответ. Новый вопрос - задавайте отдельно.